# Save Widget State Between Theme Swaps?

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I made my own custom sidebar widgets in my custom theme's functions.php file.. I noticed that when I swap my theme and then swap back, one of my sidebar loses it's configuration and I have to go in and manually add back each widget again.

Is there a way to setup the theme to save the widget configuration so that if my client swaps the theme accidentally they don't have to reassemble the sidebars again?

Comment: i will suggest to either save it in db, or hardcode in function if you haven't to change it frequently

Comment: How would I save it to the db is there a specific way to achieve that?

Comment: For that you will need to create options, you can take help from wordpress codex